# ajax won't connect with mysqli?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to connect with myqli trought a ajax call.
cause i am testing the database input of the user.

**The script is crashing at:** $testBase = new mysqli("sfd", "sdf", "sdg", "sdf");

**And in the console stands:** Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Yes u searched this question but by most people you'll get that error when you do a query and mine is doing that already when i try to create a mysqli connection.

Ajax script:

```
if (error == false){
var name = $('#name').val(),
    url = $('#url').val(),
    datahost = $('#datahost').val(),
    datausername = $('#datausername').val(),
    datapassword = $('#datapassword').val(),
    dataname = $('#dataname').val(),
    license = $('#license').val(),
    data = 'name='+ name +'&url='+ url +'&datahost='+ datahost +'&datausername='+ datausername +'&datapassword='+ datapassword +'&dataname='+ dataname +'&license='+ license;

$( "#trans" ).fadeIn( 500, function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "handlers/install.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(e){ // this happen after we get result
            react(e);
        }
    });
});
```

}

please help me

The response of handelers/install.php is:

```
"<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1130): Host 'server2.ughost.nl' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in <b>/home/universa/public_html/klant/handlers/install.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />\n<br />\n<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in <b>/home/universa/public_html/klant/handlers/install.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br />\n{\"ban\":0,\"error\":0,\"license\":0,\"url\":0,\"name\":0,\"sql\":0,\"message\":\"localhost + asd + asdas+dasf\"}"
```

Comment: where is your ajax code?? the error related with js code

Comment: i placed it in the question

Comment: Please post the php code where this error is occuring

Comment: is connection valid?

Comment: No its not valid. i am trying to check if its valid

Comment: the php code is standing in the qeustion? i know that he crashes at there cause i debug

Comment: the response tells you everything. the host that install.php resides on does not have permission to connect to the mysql server in the error message.

Comment: Some how it has now. I fixed it i'll place the fix

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was that the install.php always give a warning when the login is incorrect.
But i needed to check it because this is a users input so how did i fix it?

```
error_reporting(0);
                        $testBase = new mysqli($datahost, $datausername, $datapassword, $dataname);
                        error_reporting(1);
                        if ($testBase->connect_errno) {
                            $response['sql'] = 1;
                            $testBase->close();
                        } else {
                            //can connect with database
                            $testBase->close();

                        }
```

Comment: don't post question updates as answers, update your actual question instead

Comment: But you are asking a new question within an answer

Comment: No i said how did i fix it? and i gave the answer